# how to SoftBrick an android phone

Tags: stock-android

What is the easiest way to soft brick an android phone and i can later revive. I know this sounds awkward but i recently acquired a new phone and my son keeps on playing with my old one which has stopped him from accomplishing various tasks like house chores, homework etc

Comment: Well that's a strange situation. I softbricked my phone by trying to flash an incompletely downloaded ROM on it. I don't know if it would softbrick if you are not rooted or if it would not do anything at all. You can remove the root access later on. For your specific situation I would recommend a different approach though. You can limit his time on the phone by taking away his charger and only giving it back after doing homework or chores or whatever. Or just tell him you need the old one for work or something? I believe there are also apps available that control kids usage. Good luck!

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). Instead of trying to get your supposed solution working: Wouldn't you rather want to know how to protect your device so your kid cannot use it? Why wouldn't a strong password to the job?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.What is the easiest way to soft brick an android phone

**Flash the Incompatible (*another android Device*) Rom.**

> 2. and i can later revive

**for revive later :**

Flash the `Stock Rom` of your device and then you can use the phone.

Comment: Yepp, and backup IMEI explicitly. Its a mess in flashing.

Comment: How about a small file, easy to download and saves time. Just flash the kernel (boot.img) of some incompatible ROM. Have fun :D

Comment: There is several solution for successfully :)